# Why do Kafka partitions of the same topic contain different controller_epoch?

Tags: apache-kafka

The partitions' state of the same topic(*my_topic*) is stored in ZooKeeper as below(cluster version 0.10.0.1).

```
[zk: 172.17.41.9:2181(CONNECTED) 42] ls /brokers/topics/my_topic/partitions
[0, 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# get /brokers/topics/my_topic/partitions/[0-11]/state
{"controller_epoch":192,"leader":13,"version":1,"leader_epoch":472,"isr":[12,11,13]}
{"controller_epoch":184,"leader":14,"version":1,"leader_epoch":587,"isr":[1,7,14]}
{"controller_epoch":192,"leader":0,"version":1,"leader_epoch":517,"isr":[4,0,9]}
{"controller_epoch":192,"leader":1,"version":1,"leader_epoch":409,"isr":[8,1,3]}
{"controller_epoch":192,"leader":2,"version":1,"leader_epoch":427,"isr":[2,10,0]}
{"controller_epoch":192,"leader":3,"version":1,"leader_epoch":353,"isr":[2,3,13]}
{"controller_epoch":192,"leader":4,"version":1,"leader_epoch":419,"isr":[14,4,5]}
{"controller_epoch":192,"leader":5,"version":1,"leader_epoch":461,"isr":[6,4,5]}
{"controller_epoch":184,"leader":6,"version":1,"leader_epoch":418,"isr":[6,12,11]}
{"controller_epoch":183,"leader":7,"version":1,"leader_epoch":639,"isr":[7,1,9]}
{"controller_epoch":183,"leader":8,"version":1,"leader_epoch":615,"isr":[7,8,10]}
{"controller_epoch":192,"leader":9,"version":1,"leader_epoch":428,"isr":[8,9,3]}
```

I found there are 3 different `controller_epoch`(192, 184, 183). Does it mean some partitions(or the brokers with the leader replica of these partitions) are using out-of-date information from the cluster controller?

If all partitions of the same topic **must** hold the same `controller_epoch`, how do I fix *my_topic*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.It does not mean some partitions(or the brokers with the leader replica of these partitions) are using out-of-date information from the cluster controller. 'controller_epoch' is just a sequence which every broker holds to do a leader election. Small 'controller_epoch' means the broker has low priority to be elected to be a controller.

2.You can modify zk node to update 'controller_epoch' by set command.

```
set /brokers/topics/my_topic/partitions/[0-11]/state xxx
```

But finally controller_epoch will not keep consistency. Epoch is common mechanism to do a leader election in distributed system. You can find it in zookeeper, elasticsearch etc.